# strip remove '_' unexpectedly

Tags: python, strip

```
>>> x = 'abc_cde_fgh'
>>> x.strip('abc_cde')
'fgh'
```

`_fgh` is expected.

How to understard this result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strip removes any characters it finds from either end from the substring: it doesn't remove a trailing or leading word.

This example demonstrates it nicely:

```
x.strip('ab_ch')
'de_fg'
```

Since the characters "a", "b", "c", "h", and "_" are in the remove case, the leading "abc_c" are all removed. The other characters are not removed.

If you would like to remove a leading or trailing **word**, I would recommend using `re` or `startswith/endswith`.

```
def rstrip_word(str, word):
    if str.endswith(word):
        return str[:-len(word)]
    return str

def lstrip_word(str, word):
    if str.startswith(word):
        return str[len(word):]
    return str

def strip_word(str, word):
    return rstrip_word(lstrip_word(str, word), word)
```

**Removing Multiple Words**

A very simple implementation (a greedy one) to remove multiple words from a string can be done as follows:

```
def rstrip_word(str, *words):
    for word in words:
        if str.endswith(word):
            return str[:-len(word)]
    return str

def lstrip_word(str, *words):
    for word in words:
        if str.startswith(word):
            return str[len(word):]
    return str

def strip_word(str, *words):
    return rstrip_word(lstrip_word(str, *words), *words)
```

Please note this algorithm is *greedy*, it will find the first possible example and then return: it may not behave as you expect. Finding the maximum length match (although not too tricky) is a bit more involved.

```
>>> strip_word(x, "abc", "adc_")
'_cde_fgh'
```

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of strip. I tried to strip a `word`, which is not what strip does. thx.

Comment: @DylanSu, I included implementations to strip a single word in that case. Taking an arg list can extend this to a general case if need be.

Answer (score 1):

strip() removes characters, *not* a substring.  For example:

```
x.strip('abcde_')
'fgh'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of the strip method "The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed."  That is why every chars except "fgh" are removed (including the two underscores).